# Why is my Bootstrap-Editable with Bootstrap-tables not working?

Tags: javascript, x-editable, bootstrap-table

I am creating a table which needs editable fields..

This jquery element is appended to the page:

```
var container = $('#up-modal .modal-body');
var table = $('<table></table>');
table.attr('id','up-table');
table.attr('style','width:auto;');
table.attr('data-toggle', 'table');
table.attr('data-search', 'true');
table.attr('data-maintain-selected', 'true');
table.attr('data-pagination','true');
table.attr('data-page-size',3);
container.append(table);
```

following this, the bootstrap table function is called

```
$("#up-table").bootstrapTable({
    columns:[
        {
            field: 'id',
            title: 'ID',
            align: 'center'
        },
        {
            field: 'Permission',
            title: 'Permission',
            searchable: true
        },
        {
            field: 'Extended',
            name: 'Extended',
            title: 'Properties',
            editable:{
                type: 'text',
                pk: 1,
                title: 'Modify Properties',
                name: 'Extended',
                validate: function(value){
                    value = $.trim(value);
                    try{
                        JSON.parse(value);
                    }catch(e){
                        return 'Invalid json provided for properties';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            field: 'Access',
            title: 'Access',
            checkbox:true
        }
    ],
    data: tableData
});
```

The table is drawn correctly, but the fields are not editable.  I can call `$('.editable').editable(options)` after the table is built and that works fine, but that stops working when pagination is involved.

I am using this example as a reference https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/welcome.html

oh, and I should mention the proper scripts and css files are locally hosted and being included correctly in my html.

Library quick links:
https://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-editable/
http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woops. As it turns out, there are compatibility issues with x-editable, bootstrap 3 and bootstrap-tables.

To fix this all I had to do was include the `bootstrap-editable-tables` extension

https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/src/extensions/editable

Comment: I am having the same problem but when I inlcude the above librar I get an  class heritage jQuery.BootstrapTable is not an object or null